# Como desabilitar uma constraint no ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper, constraint

Tenho uma tabela em que dois campos especificos juntos não podem ter os mesmos valores.

**CREIO** que são eles:

- NUM_PERIODO_LANCAMENTO
- COD_INDICADOR

Supondo que tenho esses dados:

```
NUM_PERIODO_LANCAMENTO = 1 , COD_INDICADOR = 1 , COD_CR_PERIODO = 1

NUM_PERIODO_LANCAMENTO = 2 , COD_INDICADOR = 1 , COD_CR_PERIODO = 1

NUM_PERIODO_LANCAMENTO = 3 , COD_INDICADOR = 1 , COD_CR_PERIODO = 1
```

Quando tento cadastrar esses dados

```
NUM_PERIODO_LANCAMENTO = 1 , COD_INDICADOR = 1 , COD_CR_PERIODO = 2
```

o erro de constraint é apresentado.

**Gostaria de liberar esse cadastro, como fazer isso?**

Comment: Essas colunas vem de uma chave estrangeira? Tente verificar como está construído essa constraint, talvez você tenha que alterá-la

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode desabilitar a verificação de constraint através de um `ALTER TABLE` :

```
ALTER TABLE tabela
DISABLE CONSTRAINT nome_da_constraint;
```

Porém esteja ciente que isso pode gerar problemas de duplicidade em sua tabela caso você não arrume a constraint.